# Multiselect Validation In Model zend 2

Tags: php

I have a zend 2 form with multiselect box where user can select more than one item at  a time. When user didn't select any option, system give error as I have added a required validation. Now, I want to change the default message "Value is required and can't be empty" when user do not select any value. Below are 2 code. One is the model and other is the form.

```
FORM:

    $this->add(array(
                'name' => 'user_group',
                'type' => 'Select',
                'options' => array(
                    'label' => 'User Group',
                    'value_options' => $parentUsers
                ),
                'attributes' => array(
                    'id' => "user_group",
                    'multiple' => 'multiple',
                    'class' => "chosen-select",
                    'data-placeholder' => "Type Group Name Here",
                    'style' => "width:350px;",
                    'value' => $selectedUserRoles,
                )
            ));

Model:

     $inputFilter->add(array(
                    'name' => 'user_group',
                    'required' => true,
                    'validators' => array(
                        array(
                            'name' => 'NotEmpty',
                            'options' => array(
                                'messages' => array(
                                     \Zend\Validator\NotEmpty::IS_EMPTY => 'Please select user group.',
                                ),
                            ),
                            'break_chain_on_failure' => true,
                        ),
                    ),
                ));

    I want if user did not select any group from Multi Select, it gives error with custom message "Please select any group". Currently, I just set required validation but it didn't work for me.
```